# Testing React Component with Jest Uncovered lines

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm learning the TDD in React, so I have made a simple app with 2 Components and some dummy data coming from a json, and I've already written tests for those components but I still have some uncovered lines and I don't know how to test them.
Here is my code and a screenshot of my coverage:
[image]
App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import data from './data/users-data.json'
import User from './components/User/User'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {users: data}
    this.clickFollowHandler = this.clickFollowHandler.bind(this)
    this.clickStarHandler = this.clickStarHandler.bind(this)
  }

  clickFollowHandler(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const updatedUsers = prevState.users.map(user => {
            if (user.id === id) {
              user.isFollowed === 'active' ? user.isFollowed = 'idle' : user.isFollowed = 'active'
            }
            return user
        })
        return {
            users: updatedUsers
        }
    })
  }

  clickStarHandler(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const updatedUsers = prevState.users.map(user => {
            if (user.id === id) {
              user.isStared === 'active' ? user.isStared = 'idle' : user.isStared = 'active'
            }
            return user
        })
        return {
            users: updatedUsers
        }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.users.map(u => {
          return (
            <User 
              key={u.id}
              id={u.id}
              name={u.name}
              date={u.date}
              readingTime={u.readingTime}
              isStared={u.isStared}
              isFollowed={u.isFollowed}
              image={u.image}
              handleFollowClick={this.clickFollowHandler}
              handleStarClick={this.clickStarHandler}
            />
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

App.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {shallow, mount} from './enzyme';
import App from './App';

jest.mock('./data/users-data.json')
let {user} = require('./data/users-data.json')

// it('renders without crashing', () => {
//   const div = document.createElement('div');
//   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
//   ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
// });

describe('App Component', () => {
  it('calling the clickFollowHandler method from App Component has the expected effect on the state of the first user', () => {
    const AppComponent = shallow(<App />)
    const wrapper = AppComponent.instance()
    wrapper.clickFollowHandler('5d552d0058f193f2795fc814')
    wrapper.clickStarHandler()
    expect(wrapper.state.users[0].isFollowed).toEqual('idle')
  })
})




describe('App Component', () => {
  it('calling the clickStarHandler method from App Component has the expected effect on the state of the second user', () => {
    const AppComponent = shallow(<App />)
    const wrapper = AppComponent.instance()
    wrapper.clickStarHandler('5d552d00b20b141dff10d2a2')
    expect(wrapper.state.users[1].isStared).toEqual('idle')
  })
})
```

User.js

```
import React from 'react'
import classes from './User.module.css'
import myImage from '../../assets/images/avatar.png'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


const User = props => {

    return(
      <div className={classes.container} key={props.id}>
        <img className={classes.imageContainer} src={myImage} alt={props.name} />
        <div className={classes.contentContainer}>
          <div className={classes.name}>name: {props.name}</div>
          <button onClick={() => props.handleFollowClick(props.id)}>
            {props.isFollowed === 'active' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow'}
          </button>
          <input 
            className={classes.hvrIconPop}
            checked={props.isStared === 'active' ? true : false} 
            onChange={() => props.handleStarClick(props.id)}
            type='checkbox' 
          />
          <div className={classes.date}>date: {props.date}</div>
          <div className={classes.time}>reading time: {props.readingTime}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )

}

User.propTypes = {
  handleFollowClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  handleStarClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default User
```

User.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {shallow, mount} from '../../enzyme';

import User from './User';

const users = {
  "id": "5d552d0058f193f2795fc814",
  "isFollowed": "active",
  "isStared": "idle",
  "image": "./assets/images/avata.png",
  "readingTime": 20,
  "name": "Walton Morton",
  "date": "Aug 9"
};

it('renders correctly when there are no users', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<User 
    key={''}
    id={''}
    name={''}
    date={''}
    readingTime={''}
    isStared={''}
    isFollowed={''}
    image={''}
    handleFollowClick={() => {}}
    handleStarClick={() => {}} 
  />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('renders correctly when there is one user', () => {

  const tree = renderer.create(<User 
    key={users.id}
    id={users.id}
    name={users.name}
    date={users.date}
    readingTime={users.readingTime}
    isStared={users.isStared}
    isFollowed={users.isFollowed}
    image={users.image}
    handleFollowClick={() => 'test'}
    handleStarClick={() => {}}
  />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});




it('when the follow button is clicked a callback is executed', () => {
  const mockFollowClick = jest.fn();
  const mockStarClick = jest.fn();

  const tree = renderer.create(<User 
    key={users.id}
    id={users.id}
    name={users.name}
    date={users.date}
    readingTime={users.readingTime}
    isStared={users.isStared}
    isFollowed={users.isFollowed}
    image={users.image}
    handleFollowClick={mockFollowClick}
    handleStarClick={mockStarClick}
  />)

  const button = tree.root.findByType('button');
  const input = tree.root.findByType('input');

  button.props.onClick();
  expect(mockFollowClick).toHaveBeenCalled();

  button.props.onClick();
  expect(mockFollowClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith('5d552d0058f193f2795fc814');

  input.props.onChange();
  expect(mockStarClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
})





describe('User Component', () => {
  it('clicking on the button will trigger the click handler', () => {
    const mockFollowHandler = jest.fn();
    const mockStarHandler = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(<User 
      key={users.id}
      id={users.id}
      name={users.name}
      date={users.date}
      readingTime={users.readingTime}
      isStared={users.isStared}
      isFollowed={users.isFollowed}
      image={users.image}
      handleFollowClick={mockFollowHandler} 
      handleStarClick={mockStarHandler} 
    />)
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(mockFollowHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith('5d552d0058f193f2795fc814')
  })

  it('changing the star checkbox will trigger an onChange handler', () => {
    const mockFollowHandler = jest.fn();
    const mockStarHandler = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(<User 
      key={users.id}
      id={users.id}
      name={users.name}
      date={users.date}
      readingTime={users.readingTime}
      isStared={users.isStared}
      isFollowed={users.isFollowed}
      image={users.image}
      handleFollowClick={mockFollowHandler} 
      handleStarClick={mockStarHandler} 
    />)
    wrapper.find('input').simulate('change');
    expect(mockStarHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith('5d552d0058f193f2795fc814');
  })
});
```

Comment: I think the [html reporting](https://medium.com/@elisegev/running-tests-and-creating-code-coverage-reports-for-react-nodejs-project-continuously-with-60312b6a2dd0#79c7) can show you the lines that were not covered.

Answer (score 1):

Add to the scripts part in your `package.json` the following line

```
"test:coverage": "jest --watch --coverage",
```

then from your terminal, trigger that script either with yarn or npm depending on what you are using. It will prompt you to go to the specific address in your browser and you will find there complete code coverage with lines that are not being tested painted in red.

Comment: I'm using create react app scripts so the jest command won't work on my project, how can get this specific coverage that you are talking about, also is it different from the one on my screenshot?

Comment: it really does not matter that it is CRA. You can add your own scripts in package json even though you are using Create React App. You cannot customize existing ones without ejecting, but adding new ones is not a problem. Did  you try my solution? And, yes, it is different - https://medium.com/@krishankantsinghal/how-to-read-test-coverage-report-generated-using-jest-c2d1cb70da8b

Comment: Yes I tried it and it's not working, when I run npm test:coverage it shows me how to use npm, did I get it right or I should fire the command differently?

Comment: try npm run test:coverage

Comment: npm run test:coverage doesn't work it show me how to use npm

Comment: Don't know then. That should work. Are you triggering command from the project's root folder? Are you using yarn and not npm?

Comment: Yes ofc. I think it's because of the CRA